# How to repaint a Tpopmenu in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, popupmenu

I need to change the text of a `TMenuItem` in Delphi 7, when the popup menu is **already** popped up.

My popup menu has

```
OwnerDraw := true;
```

I'd like to use:

```
popupmenu.repaint();
```

or

```
popupmenu.refresh();
```

but they do not exist. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `MenuChanged` on the menu item to force it to be updated. This is a protected member to you need to gain access to that member by the well-known protected member hack.

```
type
  THackedMenuItem = class(TMenuItem);
....
THackedMenuItem(MyMenuItem).MenuChanged(True);//forces redraw of owner drawn item
```

Comment: Setting an item's caption calls MenuChanged. I wonder if there's a problem with that, or if this is a non-question.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz My impression is that user is not setting `Caption` because the item is owner drawn. The content of the menu item comes from somewhere else. I think.